# how to refresh page on IOS PWA

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a progressive web app written. I add to home screen for both Android and IOS.

on Android, if you pull the page from top to bottom by hand, it's gonna refresh which executes my main `App.vue`. On IOS, I can't refresh the page. I can navigate through links inside the app, but I can't refresh the page.

1. Is there any way to achieve this ? or i am left with no options?
2. The reason being I want to be able to refresh the page is that if user is on the app for a long time, and can't refresh the page, all the data will be old because I execute some API calls again on refresh page. What should I do?